mbedtls linking error with mbedtls_test_cas_pem
I'm compiling ssl_client1.c in the mbedtls distro with:
g++ -I/home/pi/dev/mbedtls/mbedtls/include \
    -I/home/pi/dev/mbedtls/mbedtls/tests/include \
    -I/home/pi/dev/mbedtls/mbedtls/tests/include/test \
    -L/home/pi/dev/mbedtls/mbedtls/library \
    ssl_client1.c \
    -lmbedtls -lmbedx509 -lmbedcrypto

and it fails with linker errors:
ssl_client1.c:(.text+0x158): undefined reference to `mbedtls_test_cas_pem_len'
/usr/bin/ld: ssl_client1.c:(.text+0x15c): undefined reference to `mbedtls_test_cas_pem_len'
/usr/bin/ld: ssl_client1.c:(.text+0x16c): undefined reference to `mbedtls_test_cas_pem'
/usr/bin/ld: ssl_client1.c:(.text+0x170): undefined reference to `mbedtls_test_cas_pem'

but there isn't a "test" library to link to. They are defined in /home/pi/dev/mbedtls/mbedtls/tests/include/test/tests.h and it compiles correctly but the linker won't work with those symbols. MBEDTLS_PEM_PARSE_C is defined.

turned out I needed more files as it uses the tests:
cd /home/pi/dev/mbedtls/ssl_client1
cp /home/pi/dev/mbedtls/mbedtls/tests/src/certs.c .

and some more include paths:
g++ -o ssl_client \
    -I/home/pi/dev/mbedtls/mbedtls/tests/src \
    -I/home/pi/dev/mbedtls/mbedtls/library \
    -I/home/pi/dev/mbedtls/mbedtls/include \
    -I/home/pi/dev/mbedtls/mbedtls/tests/include \
    -I/home/pi/dev/mbedtls/mbedtls/tests/include/test \
    -L/home/pi/dev/mbedtls/mbedtls/library \
    -L/home/pi/dev/mbedtls/mbedtls/tests \
    ssl_client1.c certs.c \
    -lmbedtls -lmbedx509 -lmbedcrypto

